# Android SDK. audioManager. setStreamVolume currunt int value

Tags: android, playsound

I already used below code for sound mute in my audio player.

`((Activity)mActivity).getAudioManager().setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);`

Now I need to know how to set unmute and set before volume level.

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared above is actually used to change stream volume. The second parameter of `setStreamVolume()` is value of volume.

To set volume to full

```
((Activity)mActivity).getAudioManager().setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

The volume can be changed by changing the index value between 0 and 20

Comment: Thank you. but I need reset value of volume as before I change it.